# Delphi generic record, add constraint to Equal operator

Tags: delphi, generics

I have the below record generic, which overrides the Equality operator.
The idea was to get some compile-time validation, as in the example below:

```
TpColumn<T> = record
  class operator Equal (aLeft: TpColumn<T>; aRight: String): TRec;
  class operator Equal (aLeft: TpColumn<T>; aRight: Integer): TRec;
end;

function FormCreate;
var vStrRec: TpColumn<String>;
    vIntRec: TpColumn<Integer>;
begin
  vCond1 := vStrRec = 'hello'; // should accept
  vCond2 := vIntRec = 5;       // should accept

  vCond1 := vStrRec = 5;       // should reject, currently accepted
end;
```

I could define TpColumnInt and TpColumnStr as distinct types, each its equality override (and it works), but I would like to define an array of TpColumn< T > regardless of the type T.

It isn't possible to use inheritance with records.

It isn't possible to define an array that contains different types (hence generics).

It isn't possible to override operators in classes (hence records).

The natural conclusion I've reached so far is Generic Records:

- can put TpColumn< String > and TpColumn< Integer > in the same array.
  EDIT: i understand that I was mistaken in this assumption, guess this approach won't work then.
- can overload operators

The final piece of the puzzle that still needs to be fulfilled is compile-time checking in the Equal override.  Where can I add such constraint that would solve this?

I was hoping something like this would do the trick, but it did not:

```
aLeft: TpColumn< String >; aRight: String
```

"operator Equal must take at least one TpColumn< T > type in parameters" - the compiler.

Is this achievable the way I'm trying? And if not, is there any other way to achieve it?

Comment: Your operators are wrong. They must return a Boolean. Generic types are different even if created from same template. If you want an array of different types, you could create an array of untyped pointers and have something in each pointed item which allow to differentiate what it really is at run-time. For example, the first member of all records is same type and is an enumeration telling what is pointed. Maybe you should have a look at ORM such as MoRMot which makes heavy use of generics. Full source code is available for free on GitHub. @arnaudbouchez

Comment: For my purposes i don't need them to return a boolean, and that part is working fine.

Comment: Ok thanks I'll have a look at mORMot sources

Comment: Effectively you have defined an equality condition for all types for both strings and integers so of course the compiler won't complain (although it should complain that the result is not boolean). Also arrays of records are not like classes (where instantations are pointers). All records within an array must at a minimum be of the same length. You could, of course, have an array of pointers to records, but that kinda defeats the object. You could look at variant records, but I don't think you can use managed types in the variant part, but it would have a single equality overrise.

Comment: BTW Generics don't help with arrays, be they classes or records. You *can* derive a generic class from a non generic one and get an array of generics that way, but it is not generics that are adding this capability, it is inheritance. In that regard generics are a red herring.

Comment: Why is the equality returning a non-boolean considered to be such a problem? I'm making it concatenate two strings with an '=' sign in between (stored in a record along with other stuff), and it is working fine. Would you please emphasize?

Comment: Indeed an array of pointers defeats the purpose of compile time validation. Classes and inheritance would have solved the problem if not for the inability to override operators. Each approach has slight missing feature resulting in an incomplete solution...

Comment: You're using the equal operator to concatenate strings? That's... creative.

Comment: In the scope of an SQL builder it allows the user to write plain Delphi and build the underlying SQL, without going full fledged ORM and the downsides they bring along

Comment: According to [the official documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Operator_Overloading_(Delphi)), operator `Equal` *must* return a `Boolean`.

Comment: It is concatenating correctly... Maybe the docs need an update :)

Comment: @Khorkhe: Yeah, but what if Embarcadero changes the compiler in the next update, so it no longer works? Then you will not be able to tell Embarcadero that the new behaviour is a bug that should be fixed.

Comment: Good point, did not consider this

Comment: *"Maybe the docs need an update"* Your **code** needs an update. Relying on undocumented features is a bad idea.